# how to display all the data from database in MVC5 views

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-5

```
  public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Employee/

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();

        Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.SingleOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeId == id);
        return View(employee);
    }

}
```

//here i am getting only one row with respect to id .. how can i get the whole rows from the table ?and how can i view that on the view page?

Comment: so you want all rows in your table to be displayed on another page? like the `Index.cshtml` page?

Answer (score 2):

To return the whole table, just select the whole table instead of filtering.

```
Employee[] allEmployees = employeeContext.Employees.ToArray();
```

To show them in a view, just have the model type for your view be an array instead of just a singular `Employee`.  Basically just make the model `Employee[]`.  Then you can just loop over the model.

```
@model Employee[]
@foreach(var employee in Model)
{
    // do something interesting
}
```